# Error in opening grub-customizer

Tags: grub2, customizer

I have installed `grub-customizer` in my system, Kubuntu 14.04.

When I try to start it, I get the following error, (kindly help)...

```
santosh@santosh-pc:/usr/bin$ sudo ./grub-customizer 
No protocol specified

** (grub-customizer:2992): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(grub-customizer:2992): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Answer (score 1):

To open grub-customizer simply type `sudo grub-customizer` in terminal and don't use `./` before that command.

Comment: i tried, getting the same error.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of terminal with that error

Comment: santosh@santosh-pc:/usr/bin$ sudo grub-customizer 
No protocol specified

** (grub-customizer:3065): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(grub-customizer:3065): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Comment: try in terminal: gksu grub-customizer

Comment: I get the message, 

'The program 'gksu' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gksu.'

Sorry, for asking a silly question, but is gksu different than sudo. What are the advantages of using it, in place of sudo.

Comment: you can try installing gksu and run that command again or you may find some info here http://kparal.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/how-to-run-graphical-applications-with-sudo/

Comment: This solved my problem at Fedora 22, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

where `localuser` is Your username. After that, i was able to run

```
sudo grub-customizer
```

successfully