# grub customizer terminal error cannot open display

Tags: boot, grub2, display, root

Error message when i type `grub-customizer` to terminal

`localuser:root being added to access control list`

`Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused`

`(grub-customizer:14287): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:32:45.674: cannot open display:  localuser:root being removed from access control list`

What i tried and didnt worked:

1-I removed grub customizer and reboot pc after that i downloaded again .

2-I tried downloading via terminal not by ubuntu software

(ubuntu version 21.10)

Comment: Hello. Are you logged in as root?

Comment: @David how can i check it ? ( i found it iam not logged in as a a root)

Comment: Strange question did you login as root? You do not know what name you logged in as? From your question. <localuser:root being added to access control list> it looks like you are logged in as root.

Comment: @David i mean i can see my name like this    goktug@bruh:~$    but in internet is says it shows # if you logged in as a root

Comment: @David i found the solution i typed it with a sudo comment and it worked for me thanks for all help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub customizer is not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402790/grub-customizer-is-not-opening)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Error in opening grub-customizer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464905/error-in-opening-grub-customizer)

As in here if you type with root acces

`sudo grub-customizer`

it worked for me :))